# How to pass a std::shared_ptr<Resource> to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I pass a shared_ptr by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385457/should-i-pass-a-shared-ptr-by-reference)
>   [Passing smart pointers as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826541/passing-smart-pointers-as-arguments)

Should I pass it by value or by constant reference? I have read numerous rules of thumb on whether to pass a copy constructible object by value or by constant reference. Such as:

1. pass objects by constant reference and built in types by value (except function objects)
2. pass by value unless size of the object (including dynamic memory) is less than 2 * size of a double.

Could you explain how do these rules apply to  `std::shared_ptr<Resource>`? I understand that the object is probably very small, likely a pointer and a reference counter, but it is still an object. What is the best practice here?

Comment: My rules of thumb are: pass by reference when you want reference semantics, and pass by value when you want value semantics. I think they are superior to the ones you've been reading about. (they're also easier to memorize :P)

Comment: @RMartinhoFernandes: how do const references figure into that?  The rules of thumb I often read suggest passing by const reference in cases where I'm essentially interested in value semantics (which I take to mean querying an object without changing it) and not reference semantics (where I want the ability to modify the object.)  Or were you just stating a tautology: "pass by reference when you want references, pass by value when you want values"?

Comment: References, whether const or not, provide reference semantics: when variables refer to the same object. Lack of references provides value semantics: when variables refer to different objects. What you described is mutability, which is the criterion for picking const or non-const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the most important concern (with regards to performance) is that creating a copy of a `std::shared_ptr<...>` (such as happens when you pass by value) requires an interlocked increment of a reference count.  Or maybe some other form of synchronization like a critical section, depending on implementation.  Such a cost could be significant in a multithreaded program.

Passing by reference is almost certain to be a better choice.  It's main drawback (or is this only with `boost::shared_ptr<...>`?) is that `shared_ptr<...>` offers only the standard thread safety guarantee: access to a single `shared_ptr<...>` must be guarded (e.g. by a mutex) unless all accesses are only to const methods.  In a multithreaded situation, passing around const references to `shared_ptr<...>`s may make it more difficult to ensure proper synchronization.

In a single threaded program, it probably doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: I completely disagree that this is the most important concern. The most important concern should be getting a correct program, i.e., whether you want to share ownership or not.

Comment: @RMartinhoFernandes: Good point. I think I meant "the most important concern with regards to performance."  Though I know I probably should have just answered "ask your friendly profiler about performance."

Comment: Anyway, you seem to be arguing passing by reference (leaving aside the question of why someone would even want a reference to a smart pointer) is more performant because, instead of a potentially lock-free operation, you can instead gain a synchronization problem that you can solve with a mutex. Sounds backwards to me.

Comment: @RMartinhoFernandes: Your synopsis is accurate.  Lock free operations aren't free of synchronization costs.  And I seldom find myself in a situation where I actually need to guard access to a `shared_ptr<...>`  -- I just included that for completeness.