# Check for null in std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I was wondering if i need to check whether `sp` is `null` before i use it.
Correct me if I am wrong but creating an alias will not increase the ref counter and therefore by entering into the method we are working with a shared pointer which we don't know if the embedded pointer has been reset before.. am I correct by assuming this?

```
Class::MyFunction(std::shared_ptr<foo> &sp)
{    
    ...  
    sp->do_something();  
    ...  
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba: Only if he can use C++11. Not everybody is a hobbyist programmer with control over his or her toolchain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed (and, I concede, a career in a hedge fund *is* a hobby) but developing the necessary personal effectiveness skills to move your firm forward is important.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I agree: at least write it in your own time, yes!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most shared pointers are exactly like normal pointers in this
respect.  You have to check for null.  Depending on the
function, you may want to switch to using

```
void myFunction( Foo const& foo );
```

, and calling it by dereferencing the pointer (which pushes the
responsibility for ensuring that the pointer is not null to the
caller).

Also, it's probably bad practice to make the function take
a shared pointer *unless* there are some special ownership
semantics involved.  If the function is just going to use the
pointer for the duration of the function, neither changing it or
taking ownership, a raw pointer is probably more appropriate,
since it imposes less constraints on the caller.  (But this
really depends a lot on what the function does, and why you are
using shared pointers.  And of course, the fact that you've
passed a non-const reference to the shared pointer supposes that
you are going to modify it, so passing a shared pointer might be
appropriate.)

Finally, different implementations of shared pointers make it
more or less difficult to check for null.  With C++11, you can
use `std::shared_ptr`, and just compare it to `nullptr`
naturally, as you'd expect.  The Boost implementation is a bit
broken in this respect, however; you cannot just compare it to
`0` or `NULL`.  You must either construct an empty
`boost::shared_ptr` for the comparison, or call `get` on it and
compare the resulting raw pointer to `0` or `NULL`.

Answer (score 77):

You have to consider that [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is overall still a pointer (encapsulated in a pointer like class) and that it can indeed [be constructed to internally be `nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). When that happens, expressions like:

```
ptr->
*ptr
```

leads to undefined behavior. So, yeah, if you are expecting the pointer to also be `nullptr`, then you should [check for its value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp) with:

```
ptr != nullptr
```

or

```
!ptr
```

(thanks to its [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool)).

Comment: @Jefffrey Except that `!ptr` is to be avoided, unless your goal is obfuscation.  It's present to emulate raw pointers, but this is a misfeature of raw pointers, inherited from C, and should be avoided in well written code (even in C).

Comment: @JamesKanze Both C and C++ work partially on the assumption that `0 == false`, this is all over the place and you cannot avoid it, much less move away from it. This association is engraved in my programmer brain, even though I haven't touched C in a long time, and I think many other C++ programmers feel that way, too.

Comment: *ptr and ptr-> is equivalent to: *get() and get(). That's not undefined, why are you saying it's undefined?

Comment: @Epirocks I think OP meant that it's undefined behavior when the managed pointer is null. Dereferencing null isn't defined behavior, regardless of smart pointers.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's not obfuscation, it's a basic behavior of boolean context in C and C++. Anything that is `nullptr` or `0` evaluates to false in a boolean context. That's perfectly fine. Otherwise you need to write `if (someValue == 0)` and `if (somePointer == nullptr)` all over the place. Following you logic, you must write `if (someBoolean == false)` instead of `if (!someBoolean)` right? But wait, then you need to `if ((someBoolean == false) == true)` otherwise I guess it's 'obfuscation' ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no point in passing a shared_ptr as reference.

You can obtain the internal object via `boost::shared_ptr<T>.get()` and check for `nullptr`

Also relevant: move to std :)

**Edit**: This is the implementation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp
And here is a SO thread about ref or no ref: [Should I pass a shared_ptr by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385457/should-i-pass-a-shared-ptr-by-reference)

It uses move semantics when Cx11 and copies two ints otherwise which is slower than passing a reference but when is somebody on this level of optimization?

Comment: What do you mean there's no point? We know precious little about what the function does. And you don't need `get()` to check for null.

Comment: The entire design of a smart pointer is the concept of being fast to be copied. In Cx11 it uses move semantics and prior to it it basically copies two ints, as stated in the shared_ptr implementation. This should really not be a performance impact. Testing for null should be possible without .get() you are right.

Comment: "There is no point in passing a shared_ptr as reference." - [citation needed]. You can pass by const reference (i.e. "make it clear the API of a module doesn't affect the value"), or by reference (i.e. "treat this as an output variable"). Passing by (const) reference may be mandated by coding conventions, technical reasons ("template specialization receives argument as const reference") and so on.

Comment: @utnapistim this question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385457/should-i-pass-a-shared-ptr-by-reference

Comment: @Angew With `boost::shared_ptr`, you either need `get`, or you need to construct an empty `boost::shared_ptr` just for the comparison, or you need to use the obfuscating implicit conversion.  Using `get` is probably the best (or the least bad) solution.

Comment: The top voted answer in the cited thread is completely wrong.  First, the question here (and there) involves a non-const reference.  If this is really what is wanted, it means that the called function may modify the argument, which requires a reference.  Otherwise, the shared pointer is a user defined type, so the usual rule is to pass it by const reference, and not be value.

Comment: @Samuel Copying (not moving) a `shared_ptr` involves an **atomic** increment of a counter. Atomic operations are never "free."

Comment: Samuel is correct, the author should not be passing the `shared_ptr` by reference. The "modern" convention is to pass by value [unless you are calling `reset()`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#a-namerr-reseatar33-take-a-uniqueptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-reseats-thewidget)

Comment: "There is no point in passing a shared_ptr as [const] reference.".  Yes there is.  Making a copy of a shared_ptr performs an atomic increment, and destructing it performs an atomic decrement.  These operations can consume 100+ clock cycles depending on CPU topology and contention for the count.  On the other hand, there are good (but unusual) reasons for passing by value, namely if the original value can go out of scope, the copy will retain a reference to the object.  In our performance profiles we can see the ctor/dtor taking measurable time.

Answer (score 2):

There's no general answer to this question. You have to treat it just like any other pointer. If you don't know whether it's null, test. If you believe it to never be null, `assert()` that it's not null and use it directly.

The fact that you have a reference to `shared_ptr`, or even that you have a `shared_ptr`, has no impact here.