# What is the preferred way to pass this std::shared_ptr as a function argument?

Tags: c++11

I have a very basic question about std::shared_ptr. If I have some

```
std::shared_ptr<A> p;
```

, where A is some class defined in my code, what is the preferred way to pass this std::shared_ptr as a function argument? Does it make a sense to define my functions that does something with the instance of class A like this:

```
void func(A &a);
```

and pass *p to these functions, and then convert 'a' back to std::shared_ptr with [shared_from_this()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) if needed? Is there a reason to do so and what is the common practice? Or I should pass shared_ptr as the argument like this:

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<A> p); //thread safe
void func(const std::shared_ptr<A> & p); //not thread safe
```

In the most functions in my project I can use both alternatives, but my colleague said that the first alternative is better because the reference (A&) is always better than a pointer (shared_ptr or A*), because the reference semantics implies that the argument is not null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I pass a shared\_ptr by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385457/should-i-pass-a-shared-ptr-by-reference)

Comment: Not quite a dupe, since that doesn't really address the first option (passing the pointee by reference), but definitely includes some appropriate thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a shared pointer, it does not make sense not to pass the `shared_ptr`, yet create a new one by `shared_from_this`. That's simply complicated and does not earn you anything.

The usual advice is passing objects by value if the function needs to make a copy anyway (e.g. for storing the object) and passing by const reference if the function only needs to "view" the object.

This also applies to shared pointers.

Hence, e.g.

```
// Here func in the end needs a copy of the shared_ptr, so pass by value
// the caller can decide whether he wants to move or a copy it in
struct Example {
  shared_ptr<A> m_a;
  void func (shared_ptr<A> a) {
     m_a = move (a);
  }
};

// Here func needs only a reference, so only pass a reference
void func (shared_ptr<A> const & a) {
   a->callme ();
}

// If func needs to see only an object of type A, i.e. does not
// need a pointer, it makes
// more sense to pass an A & or A const &
void func (A const & a) {
   a.callme ();
}
```

I cannot imagine a situation where passing a shared_ptr by reference would imply problems with thread safety that could be avoided by passing by value. Of course, you should avoid holding a reference to a shared pointer in a thread that does not hold a copy of the shared pointer anywhere. Yet as soon as the thread has a copy of the shared pointer, you can pass references to that shared pointer freely within this thread.

Comment: are you sure, you didn't mixed 'A const' and 'const A'?

Comment: `A const` and `const A` are the same.