# Pass reference of a smart ptr to a constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, smart-pointers

i use qcc (qnx 660) compiler (gcc 4.7.3).

I wanted to use a reference to an object in another object.
For this I wanted to pass this in a constructor call and copy/assign it to a member instance.

As I got undefined reference errors again and again I got annoyed and converted the whole thing in a simpler way and changed a refrenz to an int variable, see example.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002480/passing-stdshared-ptr-to-constructors) question, and wanted to solve it in the answer as given by @sellibitze.

Here is my code example:

***foo.hpp:***

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class foo { public:

  explicit foo(std::shared_ptr<int> stuff);

private:

  std::shared_ptr<int> mstuff;

};
```

***foo.cpp:***

```
#include "foo.hpp"

explicit foo::foo(std::shared_ptr<int> stuff)
:mstuff(std::move(stuff))
{
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

***main.cpp:***

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.hpp"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

  foo my_foo(std::make_shared<int>(10));

}
```

error message of compiler:

> *main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `foo::foo(std::shared_ptr)'*

As this didn't work either, I got suspicious and recreated the example in the online compiler, https://godbolt.org/z/83hTMq1ef.

With the gcc 4.7.3 various messages come.
With a gcc >9 you only get this message :

> :17:1: error: 'explicit' outside class declaration    17 |
> explicit foo::foo(std::shared_ptr cnt)
>       | ^~~~~~~~ Compiler returned: 1

What is the smartest way to pass a shared_ptr with gcc version 4.7.3?

Comment: Why `std::move(stuff)`? I thought that one of the points of a shared pointer was that it's actually *shared*. If you want unique single-ownership of the data perhaps you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead?

Comment: the error is not about the shared_ptr but about the `explicit`. Remove it from the definition

Comment: In your cpp, `explicit foo::foo(std::shared_ptr<int> stuff)` , that `explicit` has no business being there.

Comment: As for the "undefined reference" error, I ***guess*** it's because you don't build with all source or object files, so the linker just won't find that symbol.

Comment: Please, have a look at [explicit specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit): _The explicit specifier may only appear within the decl-specifier-seq of the declaration of a constructor or conversion function (since C++11) **within its class definition**._ (Emphasis mine.) Hence, `explicit foo::foo(std::shared_ptr<int> stuff)` in `foo.cpp` is just wrong (exactly how stated by your compiler complaint).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude true, but moving a shared pointer when applicable is an optimization because it can skip the atomic reference increment/decrement.

Comment: Ok, i just removed the *explicit * specifier of my definition, but i still can build it under gcc >V. 9 .. 

So not for my system, qnx 6.6 with gcc 4.7.3 :/

Comment: @ Some programmer dude, in my use case I give foo a ref. to a object which is my GUI interface.. 
So I communicate in more object wiht my GUI outside foo

Comment: A little nitpicking: In the example code you show there's no references at all. You pass a `std::shared_ptr<int>` object *by value*. Pointers and references are not the same.