# Passing std::shared_ptr by value or const ref and then storing in a container?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, pass-by-value, reference-counting, pass-by-const-reference

Consider the following vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> myVector;
```

and the following two functions that add a given element to the vector:

```
void foo1(std::shared_ptr<X> x)
{
    myVector.push_back(x);
}

void foo2(const std::shared_ptr<X>& x)
{
    myVector.push_back(x);
}
```

My understanding is that both functions push a `shared_ptr` to `X` into the vector and thus increment the ref count of `X`. The first function results in an additional increment and decrement of the reference count but this is needless.

Is my understanding correct? Is the second option therefore preferable?

Comment: Since you pass by value you evoke the copy constructor. Thus, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shared\_ptr by reference or by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310737/shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value)

Comment: The copy could actually be elided.

Comment: @101010 Passing by value in the first example, right?

Comment: @ksl yeap in `foo1`.

Comment: @101010 I'm happy to accept your response if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `foo1` you pass the parameter (i.e., shared pointer) by value. Thus, the copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr<X>` is going to be evoked (i.e., ref counter is going to be increased and then decreased when destructor of local copy is being called at `}` of `foo1`).

In `foo2` you pass the parameter (i.e., shared pointer) by `const` reference. Thus, you pass a `const` qualified alias of the original object (i.e., ref counter is not going to be increased).

You can also see this in the following example:

```
struct X {};

void foo1(std::shared_ptr<X> x) { 
  std::cout << "count in foo1(): " << x.use_count() << std::endl;
}

void foo2(const std::shared_ptr<X>& x) {
  std::cout << "count in foo2(): " << x.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<X> x(new X);
  std::cout << "count in main(): " << x.use_count() << std::endl;
  foo1(x);
  foo2(x);
}
```

### Output:

```
count in main(): 1
count in foo1(): 2
count in foo2(): 1
```

As you can see in `foo1` the number of different shared_ptr instances is 2. That is the original `shared_ptr` defined in `main` and the copy in `foo1`. Whereas, in `foo2` the ref counter remains 1.

Consequently, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: When wouldn't you use option 2?

Comment: @ksl basically I would use option 2 most of the time. I would use option 1 only if I wanted at some point of the function the copied shared pointer to point to somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You should rewrite your functions as:

```
void foo1(std::shared_ptr<X> x)
{
    myVector.emplace_back(std::move(x));
}

void foo2(const std::shared_ptr<X>& x)
{
    myVector.emplace_back(x);
}
```

then both versions should be more efficient, which one would depend on situation and particular compiler, most probably difference would be very small if any.

Comment: Or even `void foo1(std::shared_ptr<X> &&x)`

Comment: `emplace_back` isn't going to be any more efficient than `push_back` in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is better to pass shared pointer by reference, as atomic increments tend to degrade performance. In your case, it will not be noticeable, since you copy it afterwards anyways.

Comment: Only the `foo1` copies doesn't it?

Comment: @ksl What do you think `foo2` does internally? Do you think it does the equivalent of `new_vector_slot = x;` or do you think it does the equivalent of `new_vector_slot = std::shared_ptr<X>(x);`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The latter.

Comment: @ksl Then `foo2` copies as well.

Comment: @ksl You said both that only `foo1` copies and that you think `foo2` is implemented in a way that necessarily copies. Both of those things can't be true.