# Deduce shared_ptr T in function declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, shared-ptr

I want to write a function that looks like this:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(const std::shared_ptr<const T>& ptr);
```

so that I can call it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
Foo(ptr);
```

However, the compiler can't deduce T and I have to make it explicit:

```
Foo<int>(ptr);
```

or to overload it with `void Foo(const std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr)`.

Can I have a single declaration `Foo` with `const T` so that `T` can be deduced?

Comment: Shared pointers are designed to be copied - it's generally a bad idea to pass them around by reference

Comment: @UKMonkey that is not exactly right. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310737/shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value

Comment: @Hayt Fair enough - as said there, it's matter of option.  I'll just nod and go back to sleep.

Comment: @UKMonkey that's why I did not say you were wrong ;) it's just not black and white on this topic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `ptr` is declared as `std::shared_ptr<int>` while `foo` requires a `std::shared_ptr<const int>`. Either you declare `ptr` with the const qualifier:

```
std::shared_ptr<const int> ptr;
Foo(ptr);
```

Or you remove the const qualifier from the declaration of `foo`:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(const shared_ptr<T>& ptr);
```

Or, unless you really need to know in `foo` that you are dealing with a `shared_ptr`, make `foo` truly generic:

```
template<class T>
void Foo(const T& ptr);
```