# make_shared inside a setter method behaves like creating a copy

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm trying to use smart pointers in my class, but, I don't know why, I can't make it work. Here is a simplified version of my class:

```
class Project {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Part> getPart() const {
        return m_part;
    }
    void setPart(const Part &part) {
        m_part = std::make_shared<Part>(part);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Part> m_part;
};
```

The problem is if I pass a `Part` object (let's call it `some_part`) to the `setPart()` method and after making changes to `some_part`, the property `m_part` is unchanged, like if it points to a copy rather than to `some_part` itself. Why am I seeing this behaviour?

Comment: It's indeed a copy.

Comment: Is your goal to change root and have it reflect in Project::m_tree as well?

Comment: Why? I thought that doing `const Part &tree` was for making a reference and not a copy.

Comment: Yes. If I change the root during the execution of the program, m_root, as it points to it, should return root with its new values.

Comment: @Wizix read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is with your use of `make_shared`. That utility function is *not* intended for wrapping plain pointers with shared pointers - it's intended for [constructing a new object and returning a (shared) pointer to it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

But this is not really a problem, in the sense that you *cannot* transfer ownership of an object by passing const reference to it. So your class' interface is problematic to begin with - it doesn't fit shared ownership of a `Part`.

To do what you (seem to) want, you probably need your setter method to be something like:

```
void setPart(const std::shared_ptr<Part>& part);
```

so every instance on which `setPart()` is called gets the *same* shared pointer (or a copy thereof), and doesn't make its own.

Note: In some cases it may make sense to pass it by value:

```
void setPart(std::shared_ptr<Part> part);
```

Comment: Oh okay. So how should I do it? Pass a shared_pointer directly to the setter? I tried, but I couldn't make it works.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think I understood how it works.

Comment: @Wizix: Wait, one last point... it's not entirely clear whether it's better to pass the shared pointer by value or as a const reference. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310737/shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value).

Comment: @Wizix: And see my extra edit to your question, as you can inline methods (either in your actual code or at least here on StackOverflow, for shorter questions...)